# Python gtk3 filechooser restrict folder

Tags: python, ubuntu, gtk, gtk3

Can gtk filechooser set to be folder-restricted?

A normal filechooser will display all folder files tree starting from / (root), what I need is, to allow filechooser displaying only from `/media` folder only. So, the top visible folder is only /media, not everything else like `/home`, `/usr`, etc.

Thank you for all your kindly help.

Comment: The default widget is very generic and the goal was not to be so specific, they even say to avoid setting the initial folder. In the past I also needed something similar and i ended implementing a simple filechooser. While checking the API there is a GtkFileFilter and some properties which if correctly tweaked maybe allow you to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Limiting directory changes isn't directly available in `FileChooser`, but there are a few ways:

- You can define file filters (`Gtk.FileFilter`) but those basically filter on the file extension (or mime type).
- More interesting is that, when changing the folder, a signal is emitted called `'current_folder_changed'`. So, you could bind a function to that signal and take action. Mind: if you programmatically change the folder as a result of this signal, the signal will probably be called again, so you have to temporarily block the signal while doing that.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I solve it by using, like you mentioned `current-folder-changed` signal. Connect to a function to check the selected folder, and if it is not `startwith /media`, then `set_current_folder` to `/media`.